# In the MCU, was the Hulkbuster armor inspired by the Iron Monger armor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-age-of-ultron

A lot of the designs for Tony's beefier armors (Hulk buster, Igor) all seem to look similar to the Iron Monger armor in Iron Man 1.  I understand in the comics there is no inspiration, but in the MCU, was there any mention of Stane's armor being re-used into future Iron Man designs?

Comment: Pretty sure Hulk was the inspiration.

Comment: @CreationEdge I figured as much, didn't know if it was mentioned anywhere in a show or some side book saying that parts of that armor was used.  I always noticed some similarities between the two so I was curious.

Answer (score 1):

The armor 1st appeared in the comics in Iron Man Vol 1 #304 which came out in 1994.  It had the exact same purpose then, to allow Iron Man to go toe to toe with the Hulk if the need ever arose.
There is no reference for inspiration in the MCU.  Stark simply was covering his bases.

Comment: Technically Stark and Banner, since Bruce helped design it.